# How to show telegram bot inline keyboard button with safe url

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following code:

```
  inline_keyboard: [
    [{ text: 'Authorize', callback_data: '1', url: 'https://google.com' }],
  ],
```

When I press the button that comes out this code, the resulting url is modified to:

```
tg://unsafe_url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F
```

Then, when the user presses the button, a confirmation modal appears.

I've seen other bots with url buttons that don't have that confirmation button. For example https://ifttt.com connects with telegram and has buttons that I guess are safe.

The telegram documentation doesn't mention unsafe urls:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

I'd like to avoid that modal and go straight to the link. Is there some approval process that needs to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IFTTT](https://t.me/ifttt) is "verified" bot so it doesn't show any confirmation windows. For any other bot, if you "hide" URL in text, such window will be shown (so that user knows what website he opens).
Some clients (for example, [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org)) don't show confirmation windows for telegram.org domain.

Comment: How can I verify my bot?

Comment: Ask [@BotSupport](https://t.me/botsupport). However if your bot doesn't represent any business, they won't verify it.